# How to call mysql stored procedure with output parameter in symfony 2 using doctrine 2?

Tags: mysql, symfony, stored-procedures, doctrine-orm

I couldn't find any example to use mysql stored procedure using symfony 2 doctrine 2. Below is the signature of  my stored procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_matched_users_by_name` (IN lastname VARCHAR(50), IN firstname VARCHAR(50), IN middlename VARCHAR(50), IN debug INT(11), OUT user_id INT(11), OUT user_name VARCHAR(60))

BEGIN
 .....
 .....

END
```

How to call the above stored procedure and access output parameters user_id and user_name ?

I have already googled over similar questions but coun't find such example, also refereed to

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the native pdo_mysql connection that you can get from `entityManager->getConnection()` which returns the pdo_mysql object from which you can call:

```
$sth = $connection->prepare("CALL get_matched_users_by_name(arguments)");
$sth->execute();
```

then you need to use one of the `$sth->fetch` methods of pdo to get the results.

The reference in how to fetch from a pdo statement is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/it/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: After $connection->prepare("CALL get_matched_users_by_name(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, out1, out2)"); Do I need to call $connection->prepare("select out1, out2"); ?

Comment: @user1191081 try to check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6450557/690839